# Excess Space in GridView Flutter

Tags: flutter

How to remove the excess space between the rows in GridView. I have tried setting shrinkWrap to true but still no luck. Also, I am using expanded in the items of GridView, but it's mostly to make row of inputs look similar.

[image]

```dart
import 'package:fluent_ui/fluent_ui.dart';

class AddBillPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddBillPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AddBillPage> createState() => _AddBillPageState();
}

class _AddBillPageState extends State<AddBillPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var theme = FluentTheme.of(context);
    assert(debugCheckHasFluentTheme(context));
    return ScaffoldPage(
        header: const PageHeader(title: Text("Add Account")),
        content: GridView?.count(
          crossAxisCount: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width ~/ 500).toInt(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),crossAxisSpacing: 5,mainAxisSpacing: 5,
          children: [
            actualHisabWidget(),
            actualBheemWidget(),
            lagatHisabWidget(),
            hamaliHisabWidget(),
            actualDoriHisabWidget(),
            pdDiffHisabWidget(),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```